# PHP - Code runs successfully but nothing get inserted into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert date of birth of a user into a database i have the following code

```
<?php
include("db_con.php");
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user";
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$M_seconds = 15;
$M_tries = 3;

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
                $form = $_POST;
                $username = $form[ 'username' ];
                $password = $form[ 'password' ];
                $email = $form[ 'email' ];
                $date_of_birth = $form['year'] . '-' . $form['month'] . '-' . $form['day'];

                //add min_length to the password
                if(strlen($password) < 6){
                echo 'ERROR: password is too short';
                }else{
                //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
                $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
                $pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

                //Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM user_details WHERE username = :username";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

                //Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
                $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

                //Execute.
                $stmt->execute();

                //Fetch the row.
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                if($row['num'] > 0){
                    echo 'That username already exists!';
                }else{

                //Hash the password for security.
                $passwordHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $passwordHash = substr( $passwordHash, 0, 60 );

                //Prepare our INSERT statement.
                //Remember: We are inserting a new row into  table.
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_details (username, password, email, date_of_birth) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :date_of_birth)";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

                //Bind our variables.
                $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
                $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
                $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
                $stmt->bindValue(':date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);

                //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                //If the signup process is successful.
                if($result){
                    //What you do here is up to you!
                    echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
                }
                }

            }
}
?>
```

This code have worked for insertion of username and password but once i added the date of birth and the email I am getting this `echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';` which means that the signup process have run but I am not getting anything in my database no username,password,email or date of birth.
FORM

```
<form method="post">
  <table class="loginTable">
     <tr>
      <th>ADMIN PANEL LOGIN</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="firstLabel">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" autocomplete="off" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" autocomplete="off" /></td>
     </tr>
     <select name='year'>
        <option>2012</option>
        <option>2011</option>
        <option>2010</option>
        <option>2009</option>
        <option>2008</option>
        <option>2007</option>
        <option>2006</option>
        <option>2005</option>
        <option>2004</option>
        <option>2003</option>
        <option>2002</option>
        <option>2001</option>
        <option>2000</option>
        <option>1999</option>
        <option>1998</option>
        <option>1997</option>
        <option>1996</option>
        <option>1995</option>
        <option>1994</option>
        <option>1993</option>
        <option>1992</option>
        <option>1991</option>
        <option>1990</option>
        <option>1989</option>
        <option>1988</option>
        <option>1987</option>
        <option>1986</option>
        <option>1985</option>
        <option>1984</option>
        </select>
        <select name='month'>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        </select>
        <select name='day'>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        </select>



     <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Login" />
         <span class="loginMsg"><?php echo @$msg;?></span>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Database Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hi did you get any error?

Comment: @MathanKumar No i get no error

Comment: You aren't giving an ID for your user, the SQL you posted isn't making sure that your ID is an autoincrementing primary key, so you have to post the ID yourself.

Comment: Backtick your columns, password is reserved word in mysql. So ``INSERT INTO `user_details` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :date_of_birth)``

Comment: No errors? Are you sure? I can see that `$db->prepare` is being used without `$db` being set. Put the code in a try-catch block and see all the errors generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again with removing (:)

```
$stmt->bindValue('username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue('password', $passwordHash);
$stmt->bindValue('email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue('date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);
```

Moreover, It is better that date_of_birth data type should (date).

Comment: huh ?  care to give an explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,

if id column  is auto increment no need to give  value while  inserting

If it is not auto increment you should give id value

```
try {

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_details (username, password, email, date_of_birth) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :date_of_birth)";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);


 $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
                $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
                $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
                $stmt->bindValue(':date_of_birth', $date_of_birth);

 $stmt->execute();

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Hi can you check  try catch  it will give..error

Answer (score 0):

I have change the option box to a input filed with `type=date` now everything is working

```
<td><label>Date of Birth:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" value="" autocomplete="off" /></td>
     </tr>
```